# C# Regex.Split with Parentheses without delimiters in result

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split a string in `C#` around a `Regex` with parentheses, but I do not want the resultant array to include the delimiters.

**For example**

`Regex.Split("1;2;3","(;)")` returns **{"1",";","2",";","3"}.**

This apparently was changed in Net 2.0. Previously, it would return **{"1","2","3"}.**

How do I do this in the later .Net versions so it works like the old Net versions or like it works in `Java String.Split()`?

Answer (score 4):

Do you even need a regex here? [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would give you the exact same result e.g.

```
var numbers = "1;2;3".Split(';');
```

If you still want to use `Regex`, just get rid of the parenthesis i.e.

```
Regex.Split("1;2;3", ";");
```

Comment: No of course I wouldn't need a regex for that. I simplified the example for the purpose of the question. I have a regex that needs parentheses, namely: (\s|—|–|_)+

Comment: @D.T. I can only answer the question as it's presented, if there are parts of the solution that cannot change it's best to point these out early as to avoid people posting alternative solutions...So now the questions begs to be asked - *why* do you need parenthesis? Clearly the data doesn't have any sort of parenthesis in it so the regex doesn't need it.

Comment: Thanks, James. Do you have a way to write the regular expression that I included in the comment i.e. (\s|—|–|_)+ without parentheses?  Can every regex be rewritten without paretheses? If not, should there not be a way to split on a regex without receiving the delimiters as part of the result?

Comment: @D.T. sorry I am not sure I understand you completely. What are your *exact* requirements for splitting the string? Do you allow multiple separators? Is this why you prefer to use a Regex?

Comment: Thanks, James. Multiple consecutive separators must count as one, so I don't see how to do it without parentheses. The way it is now I can do it without Regex , but I may need to change it to (\s|—|–|_|\.{3})+ and that I don't see how to do with the regular String.Split. Either way, I would like to know if it is possible to do this with a Regex and leave the delimiters out of the results. Thanks.